# Updating a element in WPF user control

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am having a user control and which has some elements along with a ellipse. When my main window in invoked and my user control is created i have a task that loops and does some task. During the execution of this task i need to update a element in the user control. I tried with the below code but it does not updates.

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{

    ellipseRed.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher
```

This way you can update UI elements indirectly froma another thread.

Hope this helps